Проблема: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query()
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in D:\ospanel\OSPanel\domains\site\auth.php:6 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\ospanel\OSPanel\domains\site\auth.php on line 6
Вот код, как пофиксить данную проблему
<?php
session_start();
require "dbconnect.php";
if(isset($_POST['parol']))
{
$res=mysql_query("SELECT IDsotr FROM sotr WHERE login='".$_POST['login']."' AND 
parol='".$_POST['password']."' AND udal=0");
if(mysql_num_rows($res))
{
while($prise_mas=mysql_fetch_row($res))
{
$_SESSION['var']="$prise_mas[0]";
Header ("Location: dannie.php");
$ccc=date("d/m/y G:i:s", time());
$hist=mysql_query("insert into history (idsh, hist) 
values ('{$_SESSION['var']}','{$ccc}')");
}
}
else
{    //такого пользователя нет
echo "<center><br><br>Введены неверные логин или пароль<br><br> <span><a 
href='login.php'>Попробуйте еще раз</a></span> <br> или обратитесь к администратору 
системы<br>
";
}
}
?>

Пишет проблема в $res=mysql_query("SELECT IDsotr FROM sotr WHERE login='".$_POST['login']."' AND parol='".$_POST['password']."' AND udal=0"); if(mysql_num_rows($res))

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0

"как пофиксить данную проблему" --- перейти на правильное расширение и переписать код на правильный и безопасный

Ооооо, расширения 10 летней давности
